# Removeable lightsources like Minecraft

Tags: c++, algorithm, light

I have succeded with making lightsources like the ones in Minecraft and it came with a very good result. I have used the cellular automata method to create the following light.

But say I got 2 or more lightsources near each other and I want to remove one of them.
Can you recommend a way to recalculate only the affected tiles?

Here is a image showing one lightsource. https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0dqR.png

Below is my code for calculating a light source and all of its neighbors tiles.

```
void World::processNeighborLight(Tile *pCurrent, int pLightLevel, int *pIterationCount)
{
    *pIterationCount += 1; // Just to keep track of how many iterations were made.
    pCurrent->updateLight(pLightLevel);
    int newLight = pLightLevel - 1;
    if (newLight <= 0) return;

    Tile *N = pCurrent->getRelative(sf::Vector2i(0, -1));
    Tile *E = pCurrent->getRelative(sf::Vector2i(1, 0));
    Tile *S = pCurrent->getRelative(sf::Vector2i(0, 1));
    Tile *W = pCurrent->getRelative(sf::Vector2i(-1, 0));

    if (N->getLightLevel() < newLight)
    {
        N->updateLight(newLight);
        processNeighborLight(N, newLight, pIterationCount);
    }
    if (E->getLightLevel() < newLight)
    {
        E->updateLight(newLight);
        processNeighborLight(E, newLight, pIterationCount);
    }
    if (S->getLightLevel() < newLight)
    {
        S->updateLight(newLight);
        processNeighborLight(S, newLight, pIterationCount);
    }
    if (W->getLightLevel() < newLight)
    {
        W->updateLight(newLight);
        processNeighborLight(W, newLight, pIterationCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, rather than having each cell store a light level, have it store instead a collection of (lightsource, lightlevel) pairs (expensive?), and similarly have each light source store a collection of (cell, lightlevel) pairs (cheap!).

```
void KillLight (LightSource & kill_me)
{
  // All we really do is iterate through each illuminated cell, and remove this lightsource from 
  // their list of light sources
  for (auto i = kill_me.cells.begin(); i != kill_me.cells.end(); ++i)
  {
    // The cell contains some kind of collection that contains either a list of lightsources that hit it or <lightsource, illumination level>
    // pairs.  All we need to do is remove this light from that collection and recalculate the cell's light level

    i->lights->erase (kill_me); // Note light sources must be comparable objects.

    i->RecalculateMaxIllumination(); // The cell needs to figure out which of its sources is brightest now.
  }

  // And then handle other lightsource removal cleanup actions.  Probably just have this method be called by
  // ~LightSource()
}
```

If having each cell store a list of light sources hitting it is too expensive, the impact of having each light source remember which cells it illuminates is still cheap.  I can think of alternate solutions, but they all involve some kind of mapping from a given light source to the set of all cells it illuminates.

This assumes, of course, that your light sources are relatively few in number compared to the number of cells, and no really crazy luminous light sources which illuminate tens of thousands of cells.

Comment: I got some follow up questions since I did not really understand. Do each tile know what light sources affects them?
And as you code explained it; a light source should know every tile it affects?`

Comment: Each light source should probably know every tile it affects, based on your algorithm.  It's convenient and low-cost.

Additionally, if every tile knows what light sources affect it, this becomes an easy problem (at the cost of having every tile know what light sources affect it).

Even better, you could use a different illumination algorithm.  One of your problems is that the algorithm you're using isn't reversible.

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't reversible". To be used to turn down lights?

Comment: For example, addition is a reversible operation.  If you calculated light intensity by just adding up the light values from different torches then this would be a simple problem.  Removing a torch would be like adding a torch with -pLightLevel.

Comment: I came up with an own possible solution to it. I got the idea from having the tile knowing what sources affects it. And from what I can see, there is not a huge cpu overload.
http://pastebin.com/7K6RgxNh

EDIT: @QuestionC I could do that but then I would need to stack the intensity. I could have a cap at 7 if it raises above that number but it feels wrong somehow.